# Android - How to click on an item on a navigation drawer using Espresso?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-espresso

I am new to Android development. I want to use Espresso to test that my drawer opens, then click on an item and check that it opens a new activity. I've been searching for examples about this but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
@Test
public void clickOnYourNavigationItem_ShowsYourScreen() {
    // Open Drawer to click on navigation.
    onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout))
        .check(matches(isClosed(Gravity.LEFT))) // Left Drawer should be closed.
        .perform(DrawerActions.open()); // Open Drawer

    // Start the screen of your activity.
    onView(withId(R.id.nav_view))
        .perform(NavigationViewActions.navigateTo(R.id.your_navigation_menu_item));

    // Check that you Activity was opened.
    String expectedNoStatisticsText = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
        .getString(R.string.no_item_available);
    onView(withId(R.id.no_statistics)).check(matches(withText(expectedNoStatisticsText)));
}
```

This does exactly what you are looking for.

Other examples are available [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing) or [here](https://github.com/operando/NavigationViewActionsSample)

Comment: Looks like the source code link for `navigateTo` in custom ViewAction is broken.

Comment: @SudarsanGP you are right. It seems that it has been added to the android sdk. I am going to update the reference in the answer. Just use `NavigationViewActions` defined in `android.support.test.espresso.contrib`

Comment: From where did you get the `DrawerActions` class? Please add the import statements.

Comment: It is easy to find @RoshanaPitigala in the [official android dev page](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/DrawerActions)

Answer (score 2):

Incase someone else lands to this question and he/she is using kotlin you can add extension function on ActivityScenario class to grab drawer icon or back button

For more description check this [GOOGLE-TESTING-CODELAB-8](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-survey/#8)

```
fun <T: Activity> ActivityScenario<T>.getToolbarNavigationContentDescriptor(): String {
    var description = ""
    onActivity {
        description = it.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar).navigationContentDescription as String
    }
    return description
}
```

On your tests, you can do something like this

```
// Check drawer is closed
onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).check(matches(isClosed(Gravity.START)))

// Click drawer icon
onView(
    withContentDescription(
        scenario.getToolbarNavigationContentDescriptor()
    )
).perform(click())

// Check if drawer is open
onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).check(matches(isOpen(Gravity.START)))
```

Happy coding . . .